# Code execution with async

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

Sometimes when I run code made asynchronous using `async` and `await`, I find that some parts of the code don't even get executed. For example in the following code, "Sleeping2" is not shown on the console screen:

```
public static void Sleeping(int millis)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Sleeping1");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(millis);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Sleeping2");
}

public static async void SleepingAsync(int millis)
{
    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => Sleeping(millis));
}

public static async void DoSleepingMain()
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("DoSleepingMain1");
    SleepingAsync(12000);
    System.Console.WriteLine("DoSleepingMain2");
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DoSleepingMain();
}
```

Another example is the following in which neither Sleeping1 or Sleeping2 are displayed. I don't understand this because I `await` the Task in the `DoSleepingMain` method.

```
public static void Sleeping(int millis)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Sleeping1");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(millis);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Sleeping2");
}

public static async Task SleepingAsync(int millis)
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => Sleeping(millis)); //warning: call not awaited
}

public static async void DoSleepingMain()
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("DoSleepingMain1");
    await SleepingAsync(12000);
    System.Console.WriteLine("DoSleepingMain2");
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DoSleepingMain();
}
```

Any explanation (or pointer to explanations) would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've just discovered why you should never [write `async void`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2013/02/18/talk-the-new-async-design-patterns.aspx).

If you write an `async void` method, you have no way of knowing when the asynchronous part finishes.

This includes `Main()`; your program is exiting as soon as it hits the first `await`.

`async` methods are mostly useless in console programs; if you really want to try them, you'll need to call `.Wait()` on the `Task`s returned to `Main()`.

Comment: Maybe I should start experimenting with asynchrony in a WinForms or WPF app. What you said makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I agree re `async void`, but disagree re `async` Console apps. I have found them useful many times, though I usually use my `AsyncContext` instead of `Wait`.

Comment: @StephenCleary: You're right; async can be useful when running IO-bound operations in parallel.  However, console apps are the wrong way to experiment with async.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for you input. I agree with you both, that's why SLaks said "mostly" useless such as in my circumstances where there wasn't anything to keep the app from just exiting. But surely a console application could use the TPL, do lots of IO, etc...